# Функция с переменным количеством параметров

Tags: c++

Нужно написать функцию, в которую передается переменное количество параметров, написал функцию для 1 параметра(должна принимать 8-ую систему счисления и переводить в 10-ую), а вот как с переменным сделать не понимаю. Делать нужно va_list. Пытался вставить текст функции между va_start/end, но толку не дало, глупая идея? Был бы благодарен за помощь.
Обновил код, теперь функция работает, но не пойму как передать в нее несколько параметров.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <locale>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int translate(string n, ...)
{
    va_list plist;
    va_start(plist, n);
    int s = va_arg(plist, int);
    char* str = &n[0];
    int number = 0;
    int k = 1;
    for (int i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= 0; i--, k *= 8)
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '7')
            number = number + (str[i] - '0') * k;
        else
        {
            cout << "Не восьмеричная система счисления!" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return number;
    va_end(plist);

}

    int main()
    {
        setlocale(0, "Russian");
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        while (1)
        {
            int result, kolvo;
            string n, temp;
            cout << "Введите количество чисел: ";
            cin >> kolvo;
            for (int i = 1; i < kolvo; i++)
            {
                cout << "Введите " << i << "-ое число в восьмеричной системе счисления(oct) -> ";
                cin >> temp;
                n = n + " " + temp;
            }
            result = translate(n);
            cout << "Результат в десятичной системе счисления(dec) -> " << result << endl << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы поясните, что вы хотите передавать и как использовать.

Comment: Передавать введенные с консоли числа в 8-ной системы счисления в функцию, возможно не 1 числа, а 5 к примеру. Ввод нового числа разделять пробелом или же по нажатию на Enter.

Comment: Зачем вам для этого функция с переменным числом параметров? Тем более что указывать их вы должны во время компиляции, а не во время выполнения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как это совместить с вводом от пользователя - это что-то особенного :), так что я бы делал так:

```
int translate(char s[]);  // Ваша функция

...

void translate(int count, ...)
{
    va_list plist;
    va_start(plist, count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        char* s = va_arg(plist, char*);
        int res = translate(s);
        cout << s << " -> " << res << endl;
    }
    va_end(plist);     
}

...

int main()
{
    translate(3,"345","253623","4225");
...
```

Примерно так. Не компилировал, так что очепятки возможны. Просто показываю идею.

Comment: Можете мой код глянуть?) Примерно так хотел сделать.

Comment: Тот, что вверху? Простите, но нам есть три точки, но нет функции с переменным числом параметров. Вы с ними просто не работаете...

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы передаете в функцию указатели на строки, то  до кучи, еще один вариант передачи списка аргументов переменной длины. Список завершается нулевым указателем.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void
f (const char *a, ...)
{
  va_list p;
  va_start(p, a);
  const char *s;
  int n = 0;

  for (s = a; s; s = va_arg(p, const char *), n++)
    puts(s);

  printf("%d args\n", n);
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  f(NULL);
  f("1", NULL);
  f("1", "22", "333", NULL);
}
```

Вместо `puts` просто подставьте свою функцию парсинга восьмеричных чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Фух, вроде бы как разобрался. Таким способом сделал

```
   void translate_list(int n, ...)
    {
        int number = 1; 
        int *ptr = &n;
        while (*ptr)
        { 
            char s[20];
            _itoa_s(*ptr, s, 8);
            cout << *ptr << " -> " << s << endl;
            ptr++; 
            number++; 
        }
        cout << "\nФункции передано " << number << " параметра(-ов)\n";
        return;
    }
    int main()
    {
        translate_list(54, 254, 63, 345, 554, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Вы зря плодите ответы на свой же вопрос. И опять - тут у вас есть три точки, но **нет переменного числа параметров**. Все, что вы не напишете после `n`, у вас игнорируется.

Comment: Неправда. Передаю    translate_list(54, 254, 63, 345, 554, 0); таким образом и считает для всех значений)

Comment: Попытался тоже самое написать через va_list, там только 1 параметр учитывается...

Answer (score -1):

Правильно ли я понимаю?

```
 void translate(string str, ...)
    {
        va_list plist;
        va_start(plist, str);
        //for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)// я так понимаю count здесь вообще не должно использоваться. Ведь va_list, как я понял, сам должен искать в потоке нужные типы данных?
        //{
            int s = va_arg(plist, int); // далее мне нужно в потоке найти int
            //после нужно преобразовать int в char* и передать его в следующей строке кода. Не могу понять как это сделать.
            int result = translate(s);
            cout << s << " -> " << result << endl;
        //}
        va_end(plist);
    }

    int translate(char str_char[], ...)
    {
        //char* str_char = &str[0];
        int number = 0;
        int k = 1;
        for (int i = strlen(str_char) - 1; i >= 0; i--, k *= 8)
        {
            if (str_char[i] >= '0' && str_char[i] <= '7')
                number = number + (str_char[i] - '0') * k;
            else
            {
                cout << "Не восьмеричная система счисления!" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
    int main()
    {
    int result, count;
                string n, temp;
                cout << "Введите количество чисел: ";
                cin >> count;
                for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
                {
                    cout << "Введите " << i << "-ое число в восьмеричной системе счисления(oct) -> ";
                    cin >> temp;
                    n = n + " " + temp;
                }
                translate(n);
    }
```

Comment: Нет. Простите, но чтобы вам реально ответить - надо начинать с нуля и учить вас, что такое функция etc etc... Здесь не школа, лично я могу ответить на один конкретный вопрос - да, но не читать лекции... Простите за резкость, но у вас продемонстрировано полное непонимание вопроса. Почитайте что-нибудь попроще для начала.